# Making some SQL rows invisible/disabled in order to improve the SQL search (for large databases)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to disable or make invisible like the first 100.000 records in a table just to make the SQL search faster, I don't want to delete because it is important to be there, I also know I can move it to another table, but I would like an easier way to make it easier and more organized.

What i'm saying is, if for example I use some command like: `DISABLE FROM table WHERE id <= 100000` , so next time I do a search "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1" , it returns me the 100001 row without having to walk on all the 100000 rows since they are disabled.

Is this possible at all with MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a bit column, and set the bit to 0 when "disabled", and add that to your WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

If you do SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id > 10000 LIMIT 1 then as long as id is indexed, the first 10000 rows won't cause any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your SQL faster, you'd be better off looking into [Indexes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm) first.